# How to limit bandwidth and allow multiple downloads when downloading a file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, download

I have this code, that is working when only 1 download is running at a time

```
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"C:\HugeFile.GBD"))
{
    using (System.IO.BinaryReader br = new System.IO.BinaryReader(fs))
    {
        Response.AddHeader("Cache-control", "private");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fs.Length.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=HugeFile.GBD");
        Response.Flush();
        float kbs = 20f;

        while (fs.Position < fs.Length)
        {
            if (!Response.IsClientConnected)
                break;
            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)Math.Truncate(1024 * kbs));
            char[] c = UTF8Encoding.Default.GetChars(bytes);

            Response.Write(c, 0, c.Length);


            Response.Flush();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

But if I make two simultaneous connections (start a second download on the same browser) the second one doesn't execute until the first finishes.

Using a thread or a task results in an error when adding the Headers to the `Response`...

How can I make it so I can execute 2+ downloads on the same browser at the same time?

Comment: Maybe look into making this a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew.aspx) and spinning up the ones you need.  Also, you can check out [this site](http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-systemthreadingtasks) for more examples.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you do not have to use multithread for this. the server should automatically deal with this even it is a huge file. How do you test it? what if they test it from 2 different machines and still has the same issue?

Comment: Using tasks or threads, it fails at `Response.AddHeader("Cache-control", "private");`

`ArgumentException, Value does not fall within the expected range.`

Comment: have you tried adding the two following lines       Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.Clear();

Comment: +1, [`File.OpenRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx) is supposed to use `FileAccess.Read` which would allow another process or application access to the file while this operation is pending. It may not be a file access limitation like I had originally thought.

Comment: You said from the *same* browser at the *same* time yes? Like in two different tabs for example?

Comment: @BrunoLM, okay, a few years back I created a connection pooling system based off of the treads that were spawned by IIS. What I found was that a single browser with two tabs ended up on the same thread - but two browsers (even if they were the same) created *two* sessions and thus *two* threads (for long running proceses of course). It's possible you're suffering from this. Have you a way to try it from two different machines?

Comment: I have tested what Michael is saying, thats the behaviour I'm experiencing too. It doesnt matter what you do in your method; I have a simple recreate using: `public ActionResult GetFile2()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            return new ContentResult();
        }`
That is, call that twice from the same browser, the calls are sequential. Call from IE and Chrome the calls happen in parallel.

Comment: UPDATE: what browser are you using? i only get the behaviour you describe using Chrome (IE works as you want, 2 simultaneous downloads)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Google Chrome handles a download with a unique URL, so when I try to access the same URL it doesn't even run the action.

By adding anything to the URL, ex:

```
home/download?x=1
home/download?x=2
home/download?x=3
```

Chrome will think it is a different download and get it. So, to download a file, even if a different generated file every time, we need to change the URL.

And as for the throttle I created a `FileThrottleResult` which inherits from `FilePathResult`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Mvc3Test
{
    public class FileThrottleResult : FilePathResult
    {
        float rate = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="fileName"></param>
        /// <param name="contentType"></param>
        /// <param name="rate">Kbps</param>
        public FileThrottleResult(string fileName, string contentType, float rate)
            : base(fileName, contentType)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");
            }
            this.rate = rate;
        }

        protected override void WriteFile(System.Web.HttpResponseBase response)
        {
            int _bufferSize = (int)Math.Round(1024 * this.rate);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[_bufferSize];

            Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;

            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(FileName))
            {
                response.AddHeader("Cache-control", "private");
                response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                response.AddHeader("Content-Length", stream.Length.ToString());
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("filename={0}", new FileInfo(FileName).Name));
                response.Flush();

                while (true)
                {
                    if (!response.IsClientConnected)
                        break;

                    int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, _bufferSize);
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                        break;

                    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    response.Flush();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public FileThrottleResult Download()
{
    string testFile = @"C:\hugefile.zip";
    return new FileThrottleResult(testFile, "application/octet-stream", 200);
}
```

This will successfully limit the bandwidth and will not have problems with simultaneous downloads of the same file, as long as you trick the browser with a "different" url.